# Change UITableView direction to Right-to-Left

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, right-to-left

I develop an iOS application and my native language is Persian (a Right-to-Left language). How can I change UITableView direction to right-to-left in iOS programming?

A UITableView with RTL direction has:

- Icons are at right
- TableCell detail and button are at left
- TableView header and footer are right-aligned

like this :

[image]

Is there any UI or programming way to do this?

Answer (score 33):

Try this on Swift

```
tableView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

or in StoryBoard Cell properties (Semantic dropdown) select "Force Right-To-Left"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I'm aware it'll automatically change to Right-to-Left since iOS8.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this as well

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .Right

    cell.textLabel?.text = goalsArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Build your view's constraints with `NSLayoutAttributeLeading` and  `NSLayoutAttributeTrailing`  instead of `NSLayoutAttributeLeft` and `NSLayoutAttributeRight`.

Your view's Direction will be the same with  your app's  language Direction.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

for me this way worked

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)! as UITableViewCell

    //cell.myView.backgroundColor = self.colors[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text =
    "\((self.FAQs?[indexPath.row].Question)!)"

    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .right

    return cell
}
```